# Angular NgZone in marker listener

Tags: angular, google-maps, listener, google-maps-markers

I am trying to bind some angular property with the *ngIf but is not working at all.

I show you my code, first my loadMap function:

```
  loadMap() {
    this.map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), this.mapOptions);
    google.maps.event.addListenerOnce(this.map, 'idle', ()=>{
      this.addMarkers()
    });
  }
```

And the addMarkers() function:

```
addMarkers() {
    var me = this;
    this.restaurants.map( restaurant => {
      new google.maps.Marker({
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(restaurant.location.latitude, restaurant.location.longitude),
        map: this.map,
        animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
        name: restaurant.id
      })
      .addListener('click', function() {
        me.ngZone.run(() => {
          this.restaurantSelected = restaurant
          console.log(this.restaurantSelected);
        });
      });
    });
  }
```

The problem with that is even inside the ngZone.run() this is referencing to the marker and not to the Component. I don't know how could I solve the problem.

Thank you in advance.

Regards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use arrow function instead of function expression to retain `this`

```
.addListener('click', () => {
                     ^^^^^^^^
   me.ngZone.run(() => {
      this.restaurantSelected = restaurant
      console.log(this.restaurantSelected);
    });
});
```